# java connection from oracle database to oracle essbase server is breaking after 5 minutes i.e. 300 seconds

Tags: java, oracle, timeout, connection, essbase

Facing one strange issue, we are connecting from oracle database to Oracle Essbase Server using JAPI connection (its http connection and no jdbc).

We are able to execute the program till 300 seconds then we get below error: -

```
invokeMethod localException11111 ::: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: recv() timed out 
Resource temporarily unavailable 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: recv() timed out 
Resource temporarily unavailable 
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) 
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:128) 
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218) 
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258) 
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317) 
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:740) 
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:683) 
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1280) 
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379) 
at com.essbase.api.session.EssOrbPluginHttp.invokeMethod(EssOrbPluginHttp.java:139) 
at com.essbase.api.session.EssOrbPluginHttp.invokeMethod(EssOrbPluginHttp.java:109) 
at com.essbase.api.session.EssOrbPlugin.essMainCalc(Unknown Source) 
at com.essbase.api.datasource.EssCube.calcWithRunTimeSubVars(Unknown Source) 
at com.essbase.api.datasource.EssCube.calculate(Unknown Source) 
at com.ing.mass.essconnect.Database.calculate(Database.java:314) 
at com.ing.mass.essconnect.Database.calculate(Database.java:300) 
at com.ing.mass.services.Cubes.calculateNow(Cubes.java:1704) 
at com.ing.mass.services.Cubes.calculate(Cubes.java:1510) 
invokeMethod finally ::: 
TESTING .....com.essbase.api.base.EssException: Cannot connect to Provider Server. java.net.SocketTimeoutException: recv() timed out 
Resource temporarily unavailable 
at com.essbase.api.session.EssOrbPl uginHttp.invokeMethod(EssOrbPluginHttp.java:244) 
at com.essbase.api.session.EssOrbPluginHttp.invokeMethod(EssOrbPluginHttp.java:109) 
at com.essbase.api.session.EssOrbPlugin.essMainCalc(Unknown Source) 
at com.essbase.api.datasource.EssCube.calcWithRunTimeSubVars(Unknown Source) 
at com.essbase.api.datasource.EssCube.calculate(Unknown Source) 
at com.ing.mass.essconnect.Database.calculate(Database.java:314) 
at com.ing.mass.essconnect.Database.calculate(Database.java:300) 
at com.ing.mass.services.Cubes.calculateNow(Cubes.java:1704) 
at com.ing.mass.services.Cubes.calculate(Cubes.java:1510) 
Calculation completed 
Calculation completed 111 
Cubes calculateNow method finallly
```

It has been a week scratching our heads to resolve this issue but no luck so far.

Looking forward to hear back with your expert advise.

thanks in advance
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

this issue is now resolved - 
problem was with new java code which required to add a timeout parameter like this
 sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout   (set in miliseconds)